# <%- %> not escaping special characters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, special-characters

I have a form where users can sign up and create an account, any special characters get saved into my mongoDB like this `business: "Jack&#x27;s Cereal Shack"` (Jack's Cereal Shack). This is fine and I understand why it looks like that in my mongoDB, however I'm unable to escape the special characters in my `ejs`.

Everything I've come across says to just use `<%- %>`, so I try `<%- business %>` and that displays `Jack&`. Thats it.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for looking =)

Comment: `<%= unescape(business) %>`

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the `#x27;` hex character code.

```js
const business = 'Jack&#x27;s Cereal Shack';
const REG_HEX = /&#x([a-fA-F0-9]+);/g;

function decodeHex(val) {
  return val.replace(REG_HEX, function (match, group1) {
    const num = parseInt(group1, 16); //=> 39
    return String.fromCharCode(num); //=> '
  });
}

const businessDecoded = decodeHex(business);
console.log(businessDecoded);  //=> Jack's Cereal Shack
```